# Find polynomial given splitting field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Let $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ a monic polynomial such that $f$ has degree $n$. Let $E_f$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I would like to show that there exists a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $n$ such that it has the same splitting field. I don't even know how to tackle this problem. Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: as has been pointed out, it would suffice to prove that $f(x)$ and $q^n=f(x/q)$ have the same splitting field for any integer $q$. This is clear since the roots of $f$ in $E_f$ are the same than those pf $f(x/q)$ except for multiplying by a rational constant. Am I right?

Comment: Show that for any integer $q$ the splitting fields of $f(x)$ and $q^nf(x/q)$ are the same. With a suitable choice of $q$ the latter is in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: But it would not be monic

Comment: Thank you. You're right