# Existence of polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with same splitting fields.

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, splitting-field

I've been asked to prove the following statement in a Galois Theory Seminar after being introduced to Dedekind's Theorem. (I assume this could potentially help getting the answer.)

> Let $f(x)$ be a a monic polynomial of degree $N$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and let $E_f$ be its splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, there exists a monic polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $N$ that has the same splitting field $E_f$.

I can't find any way to prove it.

Any help is welcome!

EDIT: 
There used to be what I though was a counter example that has been answered already.

Comment: This is not a counter-example.  The problem is that you're assuming that $f$ and $p$ have the same roots.  This is not necessary in this case since any polynomial with integral coefficients and rational roots has the splitting field of $\mathbb{Q}$.  So, you could take $p=1$ and get the same splitting field as $f$.

Comment: BBC3, all integers are also elements of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: You're both right! I was taking $\mathbb{Z}$ as its splitting field instead which makes no sense at all. I'll edit the question to the proof only.

Comment: Are you possibly taking the same course as [the asker of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3004043/11619). My comments there settle your question also.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^n + a_1 x^{n_1}+ \cdots + a_n=0$, and write $y=Nx$; then $y^n + a_1 N y^{n_1}+ \cdots + a_n N^n =0$. Write $a_j=p_j/q_j$ and $N=\prod_j q_j$ and you are done. This is basically Gauss's lemma isn't it?